# ActiveReports 8 exports numeric data to Excel as text when using labels

Tags: asp.net, activereports

We have a couple reports in ActiveReports 8 that use label controls instead of textboxes. The problem is that when exporting the report to Excel, the controls that hold numeric values are formatted as text in Excel. This only became after upgrading to ActiveReports 8.

Initially after the upgrade, this was a problem with textboxes as well, and the way we fixed it was by changing that textboxes from using the TEXT property to using the VALUE property of the textbox. Unlike the TEXT property, we are able to assign NON-String data types to the VALUE property such as decimal or int.

Unfortunately, label controls don't have the value property. Any ideas of how to fix this issue asside from going into all the old reports and replacing all the label controls with textbox controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the issue here.  After discussing it with the ActiveReports team, the only way to get around this would be to do what said you did not want to do.  The Label control itself is a very simple control adding the value property to it would not be needed.

If we did add a value prop to label you would still need to go through every report and set the new prop.

Comment: Thanks much. We will go ahead and replace all labels holding numeric data in the Details section to textboxes.